# fast refresh in next js causing fetch error when it's use with express js

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, react-fullstack

**I'm tryin to fetch data from my api but fast refresh causing error when I try to know why I found that next js has a bug  req.params work only for once because fast refresh feature in next js do you know a solution or any other way get id from url other than req.params in express js
Thank you for your time**

[express js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meg4r.png))

[the code in next js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gefsS.png)

Comment: Before asking question, it may be beneficial to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the various pages in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75731340/edit) your question and paste your code as code blocks instead of images. What is the error you're getting? Could you add that to the question as well?

Answer (score 0):

A common issue with the router is that the query param is undefined on the first render. You can use `router.isReady` or check that the `id` is not undefined before sending the api call